# OpenGL Error when using TAndroidHelper.Context in FMX Android APP

Tags: android, delphi, opengl-es, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am developing an APP with Rad Studio 10.2 and all hotfixes.

I now have a problem with icons that I added to the APP. Under Android 5 and some Android 7 devices (e. g. HTC One AICP) the `ListView` with the self-created icons works wonderfully. However, if I test this on a OnePlus One with Lineage OS (also Android 7) or some other Android 7 devices with manufacturer OS, the images are not shown on second app start (first works). I get the following error messages (on all! Devices) in the Android LogCat between the last **`"Application.CreateForm"`** or **`"Application.Run;"`**(in `Project.dpr`) and the first call of `Form.Create`:

> 12-05 11:40:28.395 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
>   12-05 11:40:28.395 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
>   12-05 11:40:28.395 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
>   12-05 11:40:28.395 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

After that I get further error messages which look like this:

> 12-05 11:42:32.115 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-20262-0] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
>   12-05 11:42:32.115 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx W/Adreno-EGLSUB: : dequeue native buffer fail: No such device, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
>   12-05 11:42:32.115 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx W/Adreno-ES20: : GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
>   12-05 11:42:32.116 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx I/info: FMX: X_APP NAME_X: [Context Exception]: Textur für 'TContextAndroid' kann nicht erstellt werden.
>   12-05 11:42:32.118 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-20262-0] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
>   12-05 11:42:32.119 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx W/Adreno-EGLSUB: : dequeue native buffer fail: No such device, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
>   12-05 11:42:32.119 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx W/Adreno-ES20: : GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
>   12-05 11:42:32.119 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx I/info: FMX: X_APP NAME_X: [Context Exception]: Textur für 'TContextAndroid' kann nicht erstellt werden.
>   12-05 11:42:32.122 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-20262-0] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
>   12-05 11:42:32.122 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx W/Adreno-EGLSUB: : dequeue native buffer fail: No such device, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
>   12-05 11:42:32.122 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx W/Adreno-ES20: : GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
>   12-05 11:44:04.148 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx I/info: FMX: X_APP NAME_X: [Context Exception]: Textur für 'TContextAndroid' kann nicht erstellt werden.
>   12-05 11:44:04.178 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-20262-0] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
>   12-05 11:44:04.178 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx W/Adreno-EGLSUB: : dequeue native buffer fail: No such device, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
>   12-05 11:44:04.178 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx W/Adreno-ES20: : GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
>   12-05 11:44:04.179 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx I/info: FMX: X_APP NAME_X: [Context Exception]: Schattiererprogramm für 'TContextAndroid' kann nicht aktiviert werden.
>   12-05 11:44:04.179 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-20262-0] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
>   12-05 11:44:04.179 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx W/Adreno-EGLSUB: : dequeue native buffer fail: No such device, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
>   12-05 11:44:04.179 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx W/Adreno-ES20: : GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
>   12-05 11:44:04.186 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx I/info: FMX: X_APP NAME_X: [Context Exception]: Fehler in der Kontextmethode "DoFinalizeTexture".
>   12-05 11:44:04.218 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-20262-0] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
>   12-05 11:44:04.218 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx W/Adreno-EGLSUB: : dequeue native buffer fail: No such device, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
>   12-05 11:44:04.218 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx W/Adreno-ES20: : GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
>   12-05 11:44:04.218 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx I/info: FMX: X_APP NAME_X: [Context Exception]: Schattiererprogramm für 'TContextAndroid' kann nicht aktiviert werden.
>   12-05 11:44:04.218 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-20262-0] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
>   12-05 11:44:04.218 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx W/Adreno-EGLSUB: : dequeue native buffer fail: No such device, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
>   12-05 11:44:04.218 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx W/Adreno-ES20: : GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
>   12-05 11:44:04.218 20262-20262/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.Xxxxxx I/info: FMX: X_APP NAME_X: [Context Exception]: Fehler in der Kontextmethode "DoFinalizeTexture".

As far as i could inspect these errors appear after using `TAndroidHelper.Context` or changing the icons.

As far as i could inspect this errors appear after using TAndroidHelper.Context or changing the icons.

Does anyone know why this only appear on serveral devices and how to fix this?

I dont know if this errors are connected to the not showing images.

I dont get why the images are not displayed/disappearing.

Comment: There is no OpenGL on android. Just OpenGL-ES.

Comment: Thanks for this hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I built a minimal build of the app, I found out that this bug is related to TPrototypeBindSource and the live binding. If you remove this component, the images will be displayed correctly under the affected Android 7 devices. 
A bug report is available: 
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19484